# How to specify alternate online mirrors for rubygems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

The corporate filter has mis-categorized and blocked  `http://production.cf.rubygems.org`

When I do `sudo gem install ruby-debug` it gives me an error. 
There is a post on [help.rubygems.org](http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/768-installing-or-updating-any-gem-fails-with-zlibdataerror-incorrect-header-check) about this.

**How do I see what mirror it is connecting to?** What file is the mirror list stored in? **Is it possible to edit it and set alternate mirror?**

**Edit:**
Running `gem sources -a http://ruby.taobao.org -V` gives me:

```
GET http://ruby.taobao.org/specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved
GET http://192.168.1.50:15871/cgi-bin/blockpage.cgi?ws-session=1563260628
200 OK
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
    not in gzip format
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try

```
# list the sources
gem sources -l

# remove a source
gem sources -r https://rubygems.org/

# add an alternative source
gem sources -a https://gems.ruby-china.com/
```

The above shows my steps to replace the default gem source, because the connection to `rubygems.org` is unstable here

Comment: Even adding a new source is failing. `gem sources -a` gives me `Zlib::GzipFile::Error`. Is there a verbose/debug flag that would make it spit out more information?

Comment: @KshitizSharma Try the `-V` option for verbose output. Are you sure the mirror you are trying hasn't been blocked by your company?

Comment: Yes I'm sure (see the edit). But the original question is answered. Now its a matter of searching for the right mirror.

Comment: What other mirrors are publicly available?

Answer (score 0):

To get around the firewall you can remove `http` source and add `https` source.

Following worked for me:

```
gem sources -r http://rubygems.org/    
gem sources -a https://rubygems.org/
```

This is because a content filtering firewall would not be able to decipher encrypted traffic. However, this may not work if the firewall has blocked `rubygems.org` domain url.